# java util logging calls methods even when log levels don't allow them

Tags: java, logging

If I have a java util logging statement such as

```
logger.log(LEVEL.FINE, "data buffer = {0}", 
CommonUtils.prepareDataBufferString(dataBuffer));
```

Now even when my log level is not at FINE, the expensive prepare.. method  still gets called, 
which is not what I want to happen. I end up checking the logger level before this statement

```
if(logger.isLoggable(LEVEL.FINE)){
   bufferString = CommonUtils.prepareDataBufferString(dataBuffer);
}

logger.log(LEVEL.FINE, "data buffer = {0}", bufferString);
```

this increases the lines of code unnecessarily. Can I avoid having to do this somehow. please help.

Comment: FYI if you use the `if` statement, why not make the logger call directly in the following block instead of an extra variable with wider scope that you have to initialize also for the case the condition is false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A technique like this might help.

```
logger.log(LEVEL.FINE, "data buffer = {0}", 
    new Object() {
        @Override public String toString() {
            return CommonUtils.prepareDataBufferString(dataBuffer));
        }
    });
```

FYI, it's not the log framework calling the method, it's Java. Java requires that you evaluate all the parameters to a method before the method can be invoked (this is called eager evaluation, contrast to lazy evaluation).

Comment: Using the parameterized form of `log`? (eg. Logger.log(level, message, param)

Answer (score 2):

No you can't avoid it with any Java logging API that I know. There are really only two ways in the language to do what you want:

1. the if statement that you describe
2. passing an object that implements an interface into the API to produce the details.

No logging API that I know implements (2), and I'm not sure that you'd find it less verbose to pass in an anonymous object.